# Compatible versions of Spark for Sparklyr

Tags: sparklyr

Is there an authoritative source for which versions of Spark are compatible with Sparklyr? Or can anyone shed light on how to determine this?

I'm on macOS and I've not been successful using Spark 2.4.x; they all failed to connect, usually yielding a "[Failed to connect to sparklyr to port 8880...](https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+8880+)" error.

I finally got things to work using Spark 2.3.0. However, if I try to install 2.3.3, I get an error:

```
> spark_install("2.3.3")
Error in spark_install_find(version, hadoop_version, installed_only = FALSE,  : 
  Spark version not available. Find available versions, using spark_available_versions()
```

The available versions are:

```
> spark_available_versions()
  spark
1   1.6
2   2.0
3   2.1
4   2.2
5   2.3
6   2.4
```

So, this looks like an "authoritative" list but 2.4 doesn't work.

Also, does 2.3 mean 2.3.0 only? Why not support patch releases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list the minor releases with `spark_available_versions(show_minor = T)` and yes, `sparklyr` support patch releases. As of the latest version:

```
   spark
1  1.6.3
2  1.6.2
3  1.6.1
4  1.6.0
5  2.0.0
6  2.0.1
7  2.0.2
8  2.1.0
9  2.1.1
10 2.2.0
11 2.2.1
12 2.3.0
13 2.3.1
14 2.3.2
15 2.3.3
16 2.4.0
17 2.4.1
18 2.4.2
19 2.4.3
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure why `spark_install("2.3.3")` didn't work for me the first time but I tried again and was able to successfully install it.

Comment: What are those releases? Can you please clarify? In my spark version 2.4.0 I get spark 1.6.3 to 2.2.0...Is this possible?